# mergesort dividing the sequence not into half

Tags: mergesort

usually, mergesort is performed by dividing the sequence into half and recursively sorting it.
however is it also possible to perform mergesort by dividing the sequence by a third?

```
mergesort(array, start, last) {
tri_mid = (start+last)/3;
mergesort(array, start, tri_mid);
mergesort(array, tri_mid+1, last);
merge(array, start, last);
}
```

will this work?
And if it does, What will the bigO notation be?

Comment: It will work but WHY would you do that?

Comment: This is **very** similar to picking a suboptimal pivot in quicksort (hint, hint)...

Answer (score 3):

This should work just fine *if* you include a third recursive call and write the merge procedure correctly. By the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), the complexity is still O(*n* log *n*).

Comment: Why log₃? There are still only 2 recursive calls.

Comment: In fact, the question is not clear: there are only 2 recursive calls in the example code but the question could mean "3 recursive calls".

Comment: @Maxime: good point, I'd missed that. I also applied the master theorem instead of guessing the complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will certainly *work*, but the strength of mergesort is the recursive divide-and-conquer approach. If you split the list into halves each time, then you will get O(log2(n)), but this is equivalent to O(log n) because of how computational complexity works. If you split the list into two parts that are not equal, then your big O expression will still be O(log n), because you split the list into several parts at each level, but it may be slower than splitting the list in half, because the algorithm will not be working at its most optimal, which is *splitting the list*, *sorting each part*, and *merging the sorted sublists*. As food for thought, imagine what would happen if mergesort picked only the first item as the left sublist, and every other item as the right sublist. Then the big O expression would O(n^2), which is as bad as other, worse, algorithms. Of course, if you want to try out your thoughts, just do so, and time it! Then you would know for sure what is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example of such mergesort :-)

```
void TRIPLE_MERGESORT(vector<double> &A, int k, int l)  
{
if(k<l)
    {
    int one_third = (l-k)/3;
    int two_third = 2*(l-k)/3;          // k < k+one_third < k+two_third < l
    TRIPLE_MERGESORT(A,k,k+one_third);
    TRIPLE_MERGESORT(A,k+one_third+1,k+two_third);
    TRIPLE_MERGESORT(A,k+two_third+1,l);
    MERGE(A,k,k+one_third,k+two_third);
    MERGE(A,k,k+two_third,l);
    }
}
```

Where MERGE merges arrays (vectors), which can be implemented for example as:

```
void MERGE(vector<double> &A, int p, int q, int r)
{
int i = p;
int j = q+1;
int lenght = r - p + 1;
int k=0;
vector<double> merged;
merged.assign (lenght,0);
while((i<=q)&&(j<=r))
    {   
    if(A[i] <= A[j])
        {
        merged[k]=A[i];
        ++i;
        }
    else
        {
        merged[k]=A[j];
        ++j;
        }
    k++;
    }

if(j<=r)
    {
    while(j<=r)
        {
        merged[k]=A[j];
        ++j;
        ++k;
        }
    }
if(i<=q)
    {
    while(i<=q)
        {
        merged[k]=A[i];
        ++i;
        ++k;
        }
    }
for (i=0;i<lenght;++i)
    A[p+i]=merged[i];
}
```

Have a nice day :)

//EDIT://

Cannot say exactly (but probably someone else will say it better and why it is this way), but dividing into 3 parts is more complex (and need more work) than normal mergesort, so it will take more time. It will be O(n^2) I think, but for sure worse than normal mergesort :)

Answer (score 0):

If you divide the array into three parts ,the recursive equation for time complexity would be :T(n)=3T(n/3)+O(n).Using master's theorem ,the time complexity will still be O(nlogn).Even if you divide the array to as many equal parts, the asymptotic complexity remains same.The reason  for this is that ,you have to do two things in every recursion,i.e,divide and merge.Merging will always take O(n) time . So if you are thinking of minimizing your time complexity ,try to think of an algorithm which can merge two sorted arrays in less than O(n) time.